# How to create a Map from root directory to File full path

Tags: java, file, path

I am trying to make a method that compares some root path and a `File` full path and extract all directories with names and full paths to each directory into a `Map`

For example lets say I want to make a `Map` that will looks something like this:

```
Map<String, File> mapFile = new HashMap<>;
mapFile.put("root", new File("/root"));
mapFile.put("dir1", new File("/root/dir1"));
mapFile.put("dir2", new File("/root/dir1/dir2"));
mapFile.put("dir3", new File("/root/dir1/dir2/dir3"));
```

Here is the solution that I came so far:

```
private Map<String, File> fileMap(String rootPath, File file) {
    Map<String, File> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
    String path = file.getPath().substring(rootPath.length()).replaceAll("\\\\", "/");// fu windows....
    String[] chunks = path.split("/");
    String p = rootPath.endsWith("/") ? rootPath.substring(0, rootPath.length() - 1) : rootPath;
    for (String chunk : chunks) {
        if (chunk.isEmpty()) continue;
        p += "/" + chunk;
        fileMap.put(chunk, new File(p));
    }
    return fileMap;
}
```

And that is how should be used:

```
Map<String, File> fileMap = fileMap("/root", new File("/root/dir1/dir2/dir3"));
fileMap.forEach((name, path) -> System.out.println(name + ", " + path));
```

The main problem is that I don't like it and it looks like it is made just to pass the tests...And it looks terrible.

Is there any build in solutions or functionality in Java that can make this more clear. Coding something like this feels like I'm trying to find how to make a boil water. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That is error prone. What if the path is `/root/foo/bar/foo/qux`? The name `foo` is in there twice, but a `Map` cannot have duplicate keys, so one of `/root/foo` and `/root/foo/bar/foo` cannot be stored. You should re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, thank you for mentioned this. My final idea is to use a Collection (List) with Object that stores the directory name and the full path. I just made a Map example just for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class for getting directory name:

```
private static Map<String, File> fileMap(String rootPath, File file) {
    Map<String, File> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
    fileMap.put(Paths.get(rootPath).getFileName().toString(), new File(rootPath));  // add root path
    Path path = file.toPath();

    while (!path.equals(Paths.get(rootPath))) {
        fileMap.put(path.getFileName().toString(), new File(path.toUri())); // add current dir
        path = path.getParent(); // go to parent dir
    }
    return fileMap;
}
```

You can even pass `Path` as an argument directly like

```
fileMap("/root", new File("/root/dir1/dir2/dir3").toPath());
```

In this case you don't need `File` in the method at all

Comment: Thanks. Only when the rootPath is '/' there is a NullPointer but I got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `file.getParentFile()` method to get down the file path until you get to the root directory:

```
private static Map<String, File> fileMap(String rootPath, File file) {
    if (!file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(rootPath)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(file.getAbsolutePath() + " is not a child of " + rootPath);
    }
    File root = new File(rootPath);
    Map<String, File> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
    while (!root.equals(file)) {
        fileMap.put(file.getName(), file);
        file = file.getParentFile();
    }
    fileMap.put(root.getName(), root);
    return fileMap;
}
```